# Parse Json to Java

Tags: java, json, list, parsing, sonarqube

I want to parse this Json code :

```
[{"id":7,"key":"integrationContinue:integrationContinue","name":"life Portlet","scope":"PRJ","qualifier":"TRK","date":"2012-03-26T10:10:22+0100","lname":"life Portlet","lang":"java","version":"1.0-SNAPSHOT","description":"","msr":[{"key":"ncloc","val":897.0,"frmt_val":"897"},{"key":"coverage","val":0.6,"frmt_val":"0,6%"}]}]
```

I created two classes :

```
 public class Ressources {

  private String id;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String lname;
    private String scope;
    private String qualifier;
    private String lang;
    private String version;
    private String date;
    private List<Mesures> msr;


    public Ressources() {

    }

    public Ressources(String id, String key, String name, String lname,
            String scope, String qualifier, String lang, String version,
            String date, List<Mesures> msr) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.scope = scope;
        this.qualifier = qualifier;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.version = version;
        this.date = date;
        this.msr = msr;
    }
 @Override
 public String toString() {return "Ressources : \n id=" + id  + ",\n key=" + key + ",\n name=" + name + ",\n lname=" + lname + ",\n scope=" + scope + ",\n qualifier=" + qualifier + ",\n lang=" + lang + ",\n version=" + version + ",\n date=" + date;
```

}

```
 public class Ressources {

  private String id;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String lname;
    private String scope;
    private String qualifier;
    private String lang;
    private String version;
    private String date;
    private List<Mesures> msr;


    public Ressources() {

    }

    public Ressources(String id, String key, String name, String lname,
            String scope, String qualifier, String lang, String version,
            String date, List<Mesures> msr) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.scope = scope;
        this.qualifier = qualifier;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.version = version;
        this.date = date;
        this.msr = msr;
    }
 @Override
 public String toString() {return "Ressources : \n id=" + id  + ",\n key=" + key + ",\n name=" + name + ",\n lname=" + lname + ",\n scope=" + scope + ",\n qualifier=" + qualifier + ",\n lang=" + lang + ",\n version=" + version + ",\n date=" + date;}
```

(with getters and setters)

```
public class Mesures {


private String key;
private float val;
private String frmt_val;

public Mesures(){}
public Mesures(String akey, float aval,String afrmt_val ){
    key=akey;
    val=aval;
    frmt_val=afrmt_val;

}

 @Override
 public String toString() {return " \n key=" + key  + ",\n val=" + val + ",\n frmt_val=" + frmt_val;
}
```

then I created two functions :

```
 public List<Ressources> parseGson_Ressources(String jsonToParse) {

        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonToParse);
        JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iterator = array.iterator();
        List<Ressources> ressources = new ArrayList<Ressources>();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonElement jsontmp = (JsonElement) iterator.next();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Ressources ressource1 = gson.fromJson(jsontmp, Ressources.class);        
            ressources.add(ressource1);

        }

        return ressources;
    }

 public List<Mesures> parseGson_Mesures(String jsonToParse) {

        JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonToParse);
        JsonArray array = jsonElement.getAsJsonArray();

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iterator = array.iterator();
        List<Mesures> mesures = new ArrayList<Mesures>();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonElement jsontmp = (JsonElement) iterator.next();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Mesures mesure = gson.fromJson(jsontmp, Mesures.class);
            mesures.add(mesure);
        }   
        return mesures;
    }
```

then I wrote this code to get the result:

```
 String xxx = RequestSonar(); //wich return the Json result

     List<Ressources> listRessources = new ArrayList<Ressources>();
     listRessources = rs.parseGson_Ressources(xxx);
     Iterator<Ressources> iterator;
     iterator = listRessources.iterator();

     while (iterator.hasNext()) {

         Ressources ressource = iterator.next();
         System.out.println(ressource.toString());
     }
     List<Mesures> listMesures = new ArrayList<Mesures>();
     Iterator<Mesures> iterator2;
     listMesures = rs.parseGson_Mesures(xxx);
     iterator2 = listMesures.iterator();

     while (iterator2.hasNext()) {

        Mesures mesure = iterator2.next();
        System.out.println(mesure.toString());
    }
```

After executing I get this result:

```
Ressources : 
id=7,
key=integrationContinue:integrationContinue,
name=life Portlet,
lname=life Portlet,
scope=PRJ,
qualifier=TRK,
lang=java,
version=1.0-SNAPSHOT,
date=2012-03-26T10:10:22+0100

key=integrationContinue:integrationContinue,
val=0.0,
frmt_val=null
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: did you write your own code for parsing JSON in java ?

Comment: WoW, thats a lot to look at. Try using GSON, all you need is your two ValueObject class and should be good enough. Don't reinvent the wheel unless the wheel is broken

Comment: I think he's already using GSon.

Comment: I feel like there is a library that will make your job a lot easier with less bugs. Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library

Comment: He is already using Gson! The only thing is that he does not deserializes properly List/Collection and he use an hybrid technique that is bugged. Using properly GSon with List/Collections will solve his issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
i think this will help you,

create two classes with getter setter methods

public class Ressources {

    private String id;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String lname;
    private String scope;
    private String qualifier;
    private String lang;
    private String version;
    private String date;
    private List<Mesures> msr;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getScope() {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(String scope) {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    public String getQualifier() {
        return qualifier;
    }

    public void setQualifier(String qualifier) {
        this.qualifier = qualifier;
    }

    public String getLang() {
        return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
        this.lang = lang;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public List<Mesures> getMsr() {
        return msr;
    }

    public void setMsr(List<Mesures> msr) {
        this.msr = msr;
    }

}

public class Mesures {

    private String key;
    private float val;
    private String frmt_val;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public float getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getFrmt_val() {
        return frmt_val;
    }

    public void setFrmt_val(String frmt_val) {
        this.frmt_val = frmt_val;
    }

}

then use this to Parse your JSON

String jsonl = "[{'id':7,'key':'integrationContinue:integrationContinue','name':'life Portlet','scope':'PRJ','qualifier':'TRK','date':'2012-03-26T10:10:22+0100','lname':'life Portlet','lang':'java','version':'1.0-SNAPSHOT','description':'','msr':[{'key':'ncloc','val':897.0,'frmt_val':'897'},{'key':'coverage','val':0.6,'frmt_val':'0,6%'}]}]";

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Ressources>>() {
        }.getType();
List<Ressources> ressourcesList = gson.fromJson(jsonl, collectionType);

Ressources ressources = ressourcesList.get(0);
System.out.println("id :" + ressources.getId());
System.out.println("key :" + ressources.getKey());
System.out.println("name :" + ressources.getName());
System.out.println("scope :" + ressources.getScope());
System.out.println("qualifier :" + ressources.getQualifier());
System.out.println("date :" + ressources.getDate());
System.out.println("lname :" + ressources.getLname());
System.out.println("lang :" + ressources.getLang());
System.out.println("version :" + ressources.getVersion());
System.out.println("Mrs :");

List<Mesures> mrsList = ressources.getMsr();
for (int i = 0; i < mrsList.size(); i++) {
System.out.println("key :" + mrsList.get(i).getKey());
System.out.println("val :" + mrsList.get(i).getVal());
System.out.println("frmt_val :" + mrsList.get(i).getFrmt_val());
}


output:

id :7
key :integrationContinue:integrationContinue
name :life Portlet
scope :PRJ
qualifier :TRK
date :2012-03-26T10:10:22+0100
lname :life Portlet
lang :java
version :1.0-SNAPSHOT
Mrs :
key :ncloc
val :897.0
frmt_val :897
key :coverage
val :0.6
frmt_val :0,6%
```

Answer (score 3):

You could have just written:

```
public Ressources[] parseGson_Ressources(String jsonToParse) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Ressources[] resources = gson.fromJson(jsonToParse, Ressources[].class);
}
```

This should do all the work of your two complex methods `parseGson_Ressources` and `parseGson_Ressources`.

**EDIT** As per Guillaume Polet's comment my initial code was not correct. I changed the return type of the  method to array as this is simpler to implement. Still if you want to stick to the `List` solution consider his comment - it should be of help.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but `List<Ressources>.class` is actually not valid in Java. But he can use this alternative with GSon: `Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Ressources>>(){}.getType();` and pass collectionType instead of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to burst your bubble... but I would simply go:

```
new Gson().fromJson(<json string here>, MyClass.class)
```

MyClass would be the class that you generated the JSon from.  The GSon is a Google library.  If you use maven, you can include it as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It's so easy... to convert to JSon, simple use the toJson() method.

Comment: That what he is doing. Btw, GSon is version 2.1 now. The only issue he has, is that he does not use List/Collection deserialization/serialization

Answer (score 0):

If this JSON is the result of a call from a Sonar Web Service, then you do not need to parse it: just use the Sonar Java Web Service Client component, this will do all that for you and you won't need to care about JSON at all => http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client

Comment: I tried it but when I execute I get this error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONValue"

Comment: I tried this `Resource struts = sonar.find(ResourceQuery.createForMetrics("integrationContinue:integrationContinue", "coverage", "lines", "violations"));
Measure s=struts.getMeasure("coverage");
System.out.println(s.getData());`

Comment: Are you using Maven to build your project? If not, then you should: it will set you all the required dependencies in order to use the Java Web Service Client component. And I insist: we have developed this Java client so that you do not need to recreate all of the JSON parsing stuff. Once your classpath is correct, the code that you wrote just above will do averything you need, and it's that simple!

Comment: I'm using Maven I added this dependency : <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
  <artifactId>sonar-ws-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.12</version>
</dependency>

but my pom is in disorder and I didn't know how to fix it.

There is my pom http://www.toofiles.com/fr/oip/documents/xml/pom.html

Can you please help to know wich dependencies should I put.
I'm working with maven, vaadin, liferay

Comment: Remove all the other JSON dependencies, you do not need them. If you follow the documentation (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client), you'll see that you do not need many dependencies (at the beginning of the page).